# What is the difference between const std::vector<T> and std::vector<T> const?

Tags: c++, vector, constants, const-correctness

I thought the only way to declare a `const<vector>` is:

```
const std::vector<T> v;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`const` applies to the thing to its left, except for when there is nothing on the left then it applies to the thing to its right.

So, `const int a=1;` and `int const a=1;` are equal.

`const int *b` and `int const *b` are equal (pointer to a constant `int`), but different to `int * const b`, which is a constant pointer to a non-constant `int`.

This applies to all data types, I choose `int` because it is easier to type than `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: "`const` goes to the left" is ambiguous; it can mean "`const` applies to whatever is on its left" as you intended, but it can also mean "`const` should be written to the left of whatever it should apply to", which is wrong. Better to write "`const" applies to the thing to its left` or something like that, and similar with right.

Comment: And the West Const/East Const battle still continues to this day....

Comment: @Thomas thanks, applied is the correct word. When I wrote the answer I didn't want to write "thing", but didn't know what else I could write, it could be a pointer or a type.